# generate an access token for a external API to use firebase functions

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, access-token, bearer-token

I am having trouble understanding how to accomplish this. I have Firebase functions running on my application. I am using an external API in which I can configure Webhooks to hit an endpoint on my Firebase functions to perform an action. To make sure that the call comes from this external API, they recommend using an `oauth2` flow. Mainly they ask me for:

```
Provide us (the external API) with an ID and an access token; 
these are used to access a URL which provides a bearer token; 
this bearer token is then used to access the provided webhook URL until the bearer 
token expires after a pre-determined period of time.
```

And there are 4 input fields:

```
1. OAuth2 access token url
2. OAuth2 client id
3. OAuth client secret
4. OAuth2 Scope.  <---- NOT SURE WHAT THIS ONE MEANS
```

My question is how do I generate the `access token` and the `client id` for this external API?
What value should I put for the `oAuth2 scope`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure this out using auth0. In one of their documentations, they cleared explained what I was trying to accomplish. Posting here to future reference in case any one needs it.

Thanks all!

reference: https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/flows/client-credentials-flow#learn-more

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the client ID and client secret in the [Console > Credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/).

[Cloud Functions API oAuth2 scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#cloudfunctions) is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`.

Comment: Not really. The oauth2 scope you sent is for generating firebase oauth2 token for internal Firebase products. I am posting the answer now.